# Missing some APOC procedures after installing latest APOC onto Neo4j 3.1.1

Tags: graphenedb, neo4j-apoc

I installed the Neo4j APOC Stored Procedures but I only seem have access to some of the procedures. For example when I run "CALL apoc.convert.toJson([1,2,3])" I receive an error message:

> There is no procedure with the name `apoc.convert.toJson` registered
>   for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure
>   name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.

However, when I look at the available procedures I can see that a lot of APOC procedures are available such as "apoc.algo.aStar", "apoc.algo.aStarConfig" and "apoc.algo.allSimplePaths". Altogether thare are 213 Procedures Available and the majority are from APOC but it seems that many others I try to call are not available to me.

I cam accross a few suggestions in the forum but since I am using GrapheneDB for hosting I don't have many options outside of using their installer for Procedures and Extensions.

- APOC version: 3.1.0.3
- Neo4J version: Community Edition 3.1.1
- Hosted: Graphenedb

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is because many of the simpler procedures in APOC have been converted to functions, and that should cover about all the helper functions.

You can call a function inline, without needing to use CALL or YIELD:

```
RETURN apoc.convert.toJson([1,2,3])
```